# List of Promises: need explanation about the order

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

I'm writing a little script in node which grab some data from a MongoDB via Monk adapter and I really cannot figure out why the order is not what I'm expecting.

Btw, my knowledge about Promise is not very advanced:

The code I'm using

```
function bigRetry(){
  return users.find({merchant : true}).then(function(merchants){
    merchants.forEach(function(merchant){
      console.log('I see a company: '+ merchant.company);
      return jobs.find({_p_merchant: '_User$' + merchant._id}).then(SO);
    })
  })
}

function SO(jobs){
  jobs.forEach(function(job){
    console.log('I see a job: '+ job.title);
  });
}
```

What I'm expecting:

```
I see a company: JobNinja GbR
monk:queries Job find {"_p_merchant":"_User$jWDNE5b2er"} +0ms
I see a job: Praktikum Maler und Lackierer
I see a company: Freelance
monk:queries Job find {"_p_merchant":"_User$rQzEyiELOH"} +1ms
I see a job: Praktikum Maler und Lackierer
I see a company: JobNinja
monk:queries Job find {"_p_merchant":"_User$27HMaVzZfd"} +1ms
I see a job: Praktikum Maler und Lackierer
I see a company: Shore.com
monk:queries Job find {"_p_merchant":"_User$4doj3eR5kC"} +0ms
I see a job: Praktikum Maler und Lackierer
```

What I have:

```
I see a company: Freelance
monk:queries Job find {"_p_merchant":"_User$rQzEyiELOH"} +1ms
I see a company: JobNinja
monk:queries Job find {"_p_merchant":"_User$27HMaVzZfd"} +1ms
I see a company: Shore.com
monk:queries Job find {"_p_merchant":"_User$4doj3eR5kC"} +0ms
I see a job: Praktikum Maler und Lackierer
I see a job: Promoter/in
I see a job: Koch / Jungkoch ab sofort gesucht
```

If someone can explain why the queries for the jobs are displayed after the company queries and aren't "nested", that would help me.

Best,

Comment: Because in this line `merchants.forEach(function(merchant){` you enter the wonderful and mysterious world of asynchronous javascript again :)

Comment: Ok, I see should I do a plain for loop then?

Comment: Seriously though, you are invoking multiple asynchronous functions in a loop, at the same time ;)

Comment: It won't make any difference, what you need is a promise flow control for serialized execution of the array

Comment: Bluebird's `Promise.each` might be one of them, or you can write your own

Comment: What? There isn't any plain solution for that? Ok... I'm loving JS more and more :D

Comment: Well there is `Promise.all` which is part of the ES6 standard, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all . However it is not what your looking for. It will help you to return the promise from `bigRetry` but execution won't occur in series anyway

Comment: Alternative you can take a look at `co` https://www.npmjs.com/package/co which plays amazingly well with promises and is in fact implementation of `generator` executor, it will make your code a lot simpler and most probably you won't need to use `bluebird`

Comment: But even with bluebird it doesn't change the result...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111037/discussion-between-laurent-meyer-and-yerken).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Copied from discussion**
Because in this line `merchants.forEach(function(merchant){` you enter the wonderful and mysterious world of asynchronous javascript again :)

Seriously though, you are invoking multiple asynchronous functions in a loop, at the same time.
What you are looking for is a promise sequential flow control mechanism.
Bluebird's `Promise.each` might be one of them, or you can write your own.

There is `Promise.all` which is part of the ES6 standard, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all . However it is not what your looking for. It will help you to return the promise from `bigRetry` but execution won't occur in series anyway

Alternative you can take a look at `co` https://www.npmjs.com/package/co which plays amazingly well with promises and is in fact implementation of generator executor, it will make your code a lot simpler and most probably you won't need to use bluebird